# Pagination with data-toggle manipulation html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination

I have something like this

```
<div class="container">
      <h2>Pagination - site</h2>
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
<div id="tabcont" class="tab-content">
   <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane">name1</div>
   <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">name2</div>
   <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">name3</div>
   <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane">name4</div>
   <div id="tab5" class="tab-pane">name5</div>
</div>
<script>
  var i = null;
  $('a').click(function(){
    console.log(i);
    console.log($(this).text());
    if($(this).text() >= 3){
      if(i < 3 || i === null){
        $('.pagination').html('<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">2</a></li><li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">3</a></li><li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">4</a></li><li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab5">5</a></li>');
        }
        i = $(this.text);

      }else{
        if(i >= 3 || i === null){
        $('.pagination').html('<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">1</a></li><li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">2</a></li><li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">3</a></li>');
   }i = $(this.text); }
  });
</script>
```

for the first time code worked fine and pagination but next time click function not work and i don't know why?

Comment: You're replacing all the anchors with new anchors, that don't have any event handlers, that's why it's not working. You probably want delegated event handlers.

Comment: i tried delegate event and work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your script is the `i = $(this.text);` it should be `i = $(this).text();`. Here you are setting i to a jQuery object when you want the string.

The other problem is you are replacing elements that have event handlers bound without attaching new events.

Try changing `$('a').click(handler)` to `$(document).on('click', 'a',handler)`

http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data

```
  var i = null;
  $(document).on('click', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function() {
    console.log(i);
    console.log($(this).text());
    if ($(this).text() >= 3) {
      if (i < 3 || i === null) {
        $('.pagination').html('<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">2</a></li><li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">3</a></li><li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">4</a></li><li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab5">5</a></li>');
      }
      i = $(this).text();

    } else {
      if (i >= 3 || i === null) {
        $('.pagination').html('<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">1</a></li><li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">2</a></li><li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">3</a></li>');
      }
      i = $(this).text();
    }
  });
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/eae71Lqh/

Comment: i knew it with this variable i but it's too late :( but thanks and delegate event also works